# Create String array (in xml) from java array? (Android)

Tags: android

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(RoutesActivity.this, directionArray, R.id.route_direction_spinner);
```

So, I'm trying to make a spinner, and I have a java String array (directionArray).  My problem is Eclipse returns this error when hovering over "createFromResource":
  "The method createFromResource(Context, int, int) in the type ArrayAdapter is not applicable for the arguments (RoutesActivity, String[], int)"
And gives me this Quick Fix:
  "Change type of 'directionArray' to 'int'."
Basically, I have an array in Java that I need to use in an ArrayAdapter, but apparently it won't let me.  Is there a way to create an xml resource from within java, and/or a way to bypass the above error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RoutesActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, directionArray);
```

Use this then your standard:

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.route_direction_spinner);
spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Tried what you said, didn't work, but it gave me the suggestion to change it to this: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, directionArray);

Seems to be working.

Comment: Ah, basically you weren't using a CharSequence but a String. I should've caught that, my bad. Still I'm glad I helped :)

Comment: Haha, learning experience for me though.  I'd upvote but I cant yet :P

Comment: We were all there. In my case just started learning a few months ago from scratch. If it helps this is the tutorials I used to learn: http://www.youtube.com/course?list=EC2F07DBCDCC01493A - this guy is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

No, XML resources are parsed into binary format at compile time. You cannot create new XML resources at runtime.